# Ruby on Rails ERB Form for a Hash or field in a Postgres Hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, erb, hstore

in my ruby on rails project, I am using a Postgres [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html) field called `plugin_settings` to store a hash of all my plugin settings dynamically. This way if a new plugin in written, no migrations need to be written in order to save the plugin settings on my ActiveRecord object. The hash is currently PluginKey: { Plugin Settings }.

Here is my migration:

```
class AddHStorePluginSettingsToProject < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    enable_extension 'hstore'
    add_column :projects, :plugin_settings, :hstore
    add_index :projects, :plugin_settings, using: :gist
  end
end
```

Each plugin then defines it own settings, here is one example for a Build plugin.

```
def settings
  settings_list = [
    {
        key: 'url',
        value: '',
        display_name: 'Url',
        placeholder: "Add a url ..."
    }
  ]

  Hash[:build_plugin_settings, settings_list]
end
```

So here I have one setting called `url` along with a few attributes to help me in displaying the form.

I am trying to create a dynamic ERB form that will loop through my plugins and create fields for each setting, and then save it back into my hstore field plugin_settings (or a hash where I can save it after the form has been submitted. Here is what I currently have:

```
<% plugins.keys.each do |plugin_key| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><%= plugin_key %></legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <% plugins[plugin_key].project_settings.each do |plugin_settings| %>
          <% setting_list = plugin_settings.second %>
          <% setting_list.each do |setting| %>
            <label><%= setting[:display_name] %></label>
            <%= text_field_tag "plugin_settings[#{plugin_key}][]", setting_list[:value], class: 'form-control', placeholder: setting[:placeholder], style: 'width:500px' %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

The problem I am having is that my hash is being replaced completely by the value instead of keeping the other fields such as `key` and `placeholder`. I want to store the entire hash with just the `value` field updated (you can see it is currently empty in the `settings` method).

I am able to create a new hash that is sent across via `params` like this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions. But it doesn't send across my entire hash, it replaces it. I'd rather just update the `value` field and then send the entire hash back to my controller after the form submits.

Any help would be much appreciated.